# Java Jframe: rectangles on the right coordinates

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, graphics, jframe

I'm stuck on a little graphic issue here. I'm trying to create corridors(rectangles) between rooms(rectangles). The method `drawCorridors(Graphics g)`has the assignment to create these corridors, and to do so it uses coordinates from the two rectangles that sed corridor should connect between.

The ArrayList `roomList.size()`is located in another class and holds all of the rooms(which are objects), don't mind it tho, it's simply a normal ArrayList.

The rooms have their own coordinates(`X`,`Y`), `Width`, `Height` and `Color`

Now, you might be wondering; what does "room.northWall..." mean? Well, within each `room`object there is four methods that control weather the specific room has a corridor on either the north, south, east or west side. So calling "room.northWall.." for example, returns the room that "***room***" in "***room***.northWall" is connected to by a corridor through the north side. So for example if I call "room5.northWall.Height" and room5 is set to be connected with room4 by the north wall, I would get "room4.Height" instead.

```
public void connectNorthTo(Room r) {
        northWall = r;
    }
```

```
public Room(int dx, int dy, Color color) {
        this.northWall = null;
        this.eastWall = null;
        this.westWall = null;
        this.southWall = null;
        this.Color = color;
        this.Height = dy;
        this.Width = dx;
        this.Y = 0;
        this.X = 0;
        this.bottomY = this.Y + dy;
        this.RightX = this.X + dx;

    }
```

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            drawRooms(g);
            drawCorridors(g);
        }
```

```
private void drawCorridors(Graphics g) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lv.roomList.size(); i++) {

                Room room = lv.roomList.get(i);
                g.setColor(room.Color);

                if (room.northWall != null) {

                    g.drawRect((room.RightX - (room.Width / 2)), room.northWall.bottomY, 5,
                            (room.Y - room.northWall.bottomY));

                }
                if (room.southWall != null) {

                    g.drawRect((room.RightX - (room.Width / 2)), room.bottomY, 5,
                            (room.southWall.Y - room.bottomY));

                }
                if (room.eastWall != null) {

                    g.drawRect(room.RightX, (room.bottomY - (room.Height / 2)), 
                            (room.eastWall.X - room.RightX), 5);

                }
                if (room.westWall != null) {

                    g.drawRect(room.westWall.RightX, (room.bottomY - (room.Height / 2)),
                            (room.X - room.westWall.RightX), 5);

        }
    }
}
```

The rectangles work perfectly fine, and are at the intended coordinates and dimensions.

***The problem*** is that I get this output: (minus the `set.fillrect` which I removed to minimize code)

[image]

Which is of course not what I intended, At All.

I tried it with only two rooms and putting the X to 10 and the Y to 20 for the corridor to see how it would react. And... this happened... (this was with the left room connected to the right room with a corridor on the east side.)

[image]

I put a `print` to get the coordinates and dimensions of the placed corridors(continuing the test above with only two rooms). And I got this output.

```
corridor has been placed at (100,50) and has the width: 530 and height: 5
corridor has been placed at (100,50) and has the width: 530 and height: 5
corridor has been placed at (100,50) and has the width: 530 and height: 5
corridor has been placed at (100,50) and has the width: 530 and height: 5
```

which doesn't make much sense. For one, there are four of them, and second of they're at (100, 50) which they shouldn't. And the dimensions are wrong, shouldn't have a 530 width, it should be 30.

Comment: Obviously most rooms will eventually have their `X` and `Y` fields changed to be something other than zero.  When that happens, are you sure your Room class is updating `RightX` and `bottomY` accordingly?  (By the way, Java convention is that all non-static fields should have names starting with a lowercase letter.  Names that start with an uppercase letter tend to look like class names when others read the code.)

Comment: Thanks! figured it out. I needed to update ```roomHeight``` and ```roomWidth```efter updating X and Y.